How to add the property list "category" to the Transactions list to a Sandbox/Test User in Plaid?
On the Sandbox of the Plaid Dashboard I have tried unsuccessfully to add a Test User that on the config json has a list of Transactions where I can add the "category" property, since in the documentation it shows there exist such a property, but when I try to save it I get the following error message: "does not match expected schema".
For example this transaction:
{
    "amount": -816.65,
    "currency": "USD",
    "date_posted": "2024-03-19",
    "date_transacted": "2024-03-18",
    "description": "DEBIT CRD AUTOPAY 94412 000000002879123 KIUWPWRSXTKF UXYOTLLKJHA C",
    "category": [
        "Transaction",
        "Deposit"
    ]
}

I tried removing the category property and the json got saved successfully. I need that list of categories so that I can better distinguish between Deposits and Withdrawals, among obtaining other valuable information.

The Plaid Sandbox custom user configuration object schema doesn't support providing categories to test transactions. To test in Sandbox with more detailed test data that does have categories, try using the user_transactions_dynamic test user (password: any non-blank password), which is designed to have realistic, detailed category data.
Custom user configuration object schema:
https://plaid.com/docs/sandbox/user-custom/#configuration-object-schema
Test user details:
https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/#testing-transactions-in-sandbox
